# JSON [object Object] Data Pulling (unable to get object data)

Tags: javascript, json, api, object

**Introduction** 
Hello, I am having a problem where I pull API data using JSON but then I have problems showing or working with the Data.

**My Code**

```
function pullingInformation () {
    var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data.open('GET', 'RANDOM URL CANT SHOW API KEY');

    data.onload = function () {
        if (data.status >= 200 && data.status < 400) {
            // Different types of JSON.random(). Examples are: parse() and stringify();
            var ourData = JSON.stringify(data.responseText);
            var tempOurData = JSON.parse(ourData);
            tempHTML = WeatherHTML(tempOurData);
            $('#DivID').html(tempHTML);
        }
        else {
            $('#DivID').html('Server failure, please try again!');
        }
    };

    data.onerror = function () {
        $('#DivID').html('Connection error ocurred, please try again!');
    }
}

function WeatherHTML (data) {
    tempHTML = data;
    console.log(tempHTML);
console.log(tempHTML.coord);
    return tempHTML.coord;
}
```

**Problem** 
When I `console.log()` tempHTML I get the entire code from the API but if I try taking just a specific bit of the code which looks like this:

`{"coord":{"lon":45.1,"lat":12.45},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"base":"stations","main:{"temp":298.508,"pressure":1031.37,"humidity":97,"temp_min":298.508,"temp_max":298.508,"sea_level":1031.75,"grnd_level":1031.37},"wind":{"speed":5.72,"deg":92.5012},"clouds":{"all":12},"dt":1515515421,"sys":{"message":0.0155,"country":"YE","sunrise":1515468218,"sunset":1515509418},"id":6940814,"name":"Craiter","cod":200}`

for example `tempHTML.coord` returns me 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong and where is my mistake? Am I simply pulling the information wrong or calling the object in a non-correct method?

Comment: "tempHTML.coord" — You don't use this anywhere in your main code example. You should provide a real [mcve] that isn't fragmented.

Comment: You should [enable Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Implicit globals are a good way to write hard to maintain code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Also, where could my mistake be, I will edit question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var ourData = JSON.stringify(data.responseText);
> ```

Here you take the *string of JSON which represents an object* and convert it to a *string of JSON which represents a **string of JSON** which represents an object*.

> ```
> var tempOurData = JSON.parse(ourData);
> ```

Then you reverse that, giving yourself the original string of JSON.

This is entirely pointless and you would have got the same effect with:

```
var tempOurData = data.responseText;
```

> ```
> tempHTML = WeatherHTML(tempOurData);
> ```

Then you pass it through a function, which logs it, assigns it to a global, then returns it. You then assign it to the same global, overwriting the identical string already there.

> ```
> tempHTML.coord
> ```

Then you try to read the `coord` property of the string. It is undefined because strings don't have a `coord` property.

---

You need to parse the **original** JSON to turn it into an object. Then you can access its properties.

```
if (data.status >= 200 && data.status < 400) {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    console.log(ourData.coord);
}
```

---

In addition, you need to fix your JSON. It is invalid. You are missing a quote. [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com/) will highlight exactly where.

---

> ```
> $('#DivID').html(tempHTML);
> ```

jQuery's `html` method expects to be passed a string, jQuery object or DOM object.

`{"lon":45.1,"lat":12.45}` is a plain object and not one of the above data types. jQuery will treat it as if it were an empty string.

Comment: I have a problem. Try adding any of the data in a html element like a div. It still doesn't work

Comment: But try adding something like ourData.coord or ourData.name not just ourData because that works

Comment: Never mind, I made it working with a different method, point is I made it work